# How should I change the value of Boolean variable in JUNIT?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, boolean

```
public ClaimEntity create(ClaimEntity entity) {

    if (isBillEstimationActive) {
        return be_save(entity, BE_INSERT, new GeneratedKeyHolder());
    }

    return save(entity, INSERT, new GeneratedKeyHolder());
}
```

And the boolean variable is been set at the beginning of the class

`private boolean isBillEstimationActive = false;`

I want to call **be_save** and it won't be called until and unless it's the value of bool is true.
How should I achieve it in my test case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to set your private boolean field to true before to test it. If you have no other case like this you should use Java reflexion.

This is an example supposing your code is from `ClaimRepository` class :

```
ClaimRepository repository = new ClaimRepository();
Field field = ClaimEntity.getDeclaredField(isBillEstimationActive);
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(repository, true);
```

You could also take a look to this answer : [How do I test a private function or a class that has private methods, fields or inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-do-i-test-a-private-function-or-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or)

Answer (score -1):

You need to change that private variable's value by true.

for that you need to use **PowerMock - WhiteBox** class.

> for example

`Whitebox.setInternalState(classObject, “isBillEstimationActive”, true);`

above statement while change the private variable's value.

for more information you can follow below link. [WhiteBox.java](https://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-reflect/1.7.0/org/powermock/reflect/Whitebox.html)